# Scala Pattern Matching Error, "bad simple pattern: bad use of _* (sequence pattern not allowed)"

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I was writing an assignment from Coursera and I met a problem about Scala Pattern Matching.

The book "Programming in Scala" has the following code:

```
expr match { 
    case List(0, _ * ) => println("found it") 
    case _ => 
}
```

So I wrote a similiar code to calculate the frequency of each character in a list:

```
/**
 * This function computes for each unique character in the list `chars` the number of
 * times it occurs. For example, the invocation
 *
 *   times(List('a', 'b', 'a'))
 *
 * should return the following (the order of the resulting list is not important):
 *
 *   List(('a', 2), ('b', 1)) */
 def times(chars: List[Char]): List[(Char, Int)] = {
   def addTime(char: Char, times: List[(Char, Int)]):List[(Char, Int)] = times match {
     case List(head @ (_*), (c , times), tail @ (_*)) if c == char => List(head, (c, times + 1), tail)
     case _ => List((char, 1))
 }

   if(chars.isEmpty) Nil else addTime(chars.head, times(chars.tail))
}
```

However, the compiler complains:

```
Error:(81, 29) bad simple pattern: bad use of _* (sequence pattern not allowed)
    case List(head @ (_*), (c , times), tail @ (_*)) if c == char => List(head, (c, times + 1), tail)
```

Though I successfully implemented this method in another way, with the help of 2 helper functions, I did not know why does this sequence pattern was not allowed. I tried to Google but I could not find an answer.

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had a bit of a hard time understanding, what your code should express, and I guess I finally found out (the line with 2 times the '@' symbol): match a list  where somewhere a tuple (c, n) has a c, matching (char). I'm not really familiar with the @-Syntax and its use cases, but have never seen a multiple, variable length matching like this of head and tail - beside to note, that the data structure does not guarantee for only a single match in c. Since I suspect, that you're more interested in the _* - thingy, I don't post my own solution (foldLeft + pattern matching)

Comment: @userunknown Thank you, buddy. What you said is exactly what I want to match. The reason is that _* is not allowed to be used at the head, as you suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any pattern match only decomposes the original value in at most one way. If `case List(head @ (_*), (c , times), tail @ (_*))` was legal, it would allow many options for `head`, `c`, `times`, and `tail`. Your intention seems to be that all of these ways are tried in order, and matched when the guard `c == char` becomes true, but this is not how Scala pattern matching works.

In fact, to make rules simple, `_*` is only allowed at the end. Something like `List(_*, c)` *could* be reasonably allowed, but it isn't.

Comment: Thanks a lot! My mistake is placing _* at the head as you suggested. I read the chapter of pattern match again and there is a sentence: "If you want to match against a sequence without specifying how long it can be, you can specify _ * as the last element of the pattern."